# select count(*) with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a query where I try to retrieve the number of rows but in my case drops as result 1 on each time. I suppose that is a join problem and I don't kniw how to handle this

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS summe 
FROM
  feeds 
  LEFT JOIN cat_product cp 
    ON cp.product_id = feeds.productid 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND cp.price BETWEEN 950 
  AND 1450 
  AND cp.ram_cap BETWEEN 5 
  AND 11 
  AND feeds.tdcategoryname LIKE '%Laptop%' 
  AND feeds.brand IN ('Dell', 'Lenovo', 'Acer', 'Asus') 
GROUP BY cp.product_id
```

Comment: What is `WHERE 1 = 1` for? `COUNT(feeds.*)` or `COUNT(cp.*)` ?

Comment: I make dynamical queries with php and where 1=1 is to avoid complications on the flow

Comment: we always make dynamic queries with PHP too. But we never use `WHERE 1=1`  this does not affect the result.

Comment: The question is what do you want to count?
If you just want to count the rows fitting the conditions, leave out the group by...

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` is really an `INNER JOIN` because of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  If you're trying to return all rows in `feeds` regardless of whether there's a `cat_product` row (ie, get a `0` count), you're going to need to move the `cp.  ` conditions up into the join.  Also,  where do your next/previous ranges start?  Remember that `BETWEEN` equates to `cp.price >= 950 AND cp.price <= 1450`, so if the next range starts at 1450, and there's a row with that value, it'll be included twice.  For this, and other reasons, prefer an exclusive upper bound (`<`) instead.

Comment: @Özkan ÖZLÜ thank  you for your feedback u are right (WHERE 1=1) that should not be used, but sometimes others errors to re-factorize it takes time

Comment: @kanoca  I've seen it used by people so that they don't have to worry about `AND` or `OR` keywords when commenting out other where clauses.  All lines written can start with `AND`

Imagine `1=1` was not present int he above query. If for instance someone were to try and comment out the first clause, the following clause would lead with `AND`, thus, be invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, not sure if you are using `MySQL` or `MSSQL`. Since you `LEFT JOIN` there is a possibility that a value is `NULL`. In `MSSQL` if a `NULL` value is accounted for the the result will be `NULL` Always when using a aggregated function like `COUNT`.

For MySQL

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(IFNULL(cp.Procuct_id,0)) AS summe 
FROM
  feeds 
  LEFT JOIN cat_product cp 
    ON cp.product_id = feeds.productid 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND cp.price BETWEEN 950 
  AND 1450 
  AND cp.ram_cap BETWEEN 5 
  AND 11 
  AND feeds.tdcategoryname LIKE '%Laptop%' 
  AND feeds.brand IN ('Dell', 'Lenovo', 'Acer', 'Asus')
```

Comment: thanks I was trying the mysql version but drops the same result

Comment: Do you want to count the cp.Product_Id?

Comment: yes I would like to count cp.product_id, removing GROUP BY as @ Jan Zeiseweis suggested than it works

Comment: Wow im not awake yes the GROUP BY is not needed as its only the count and not a count for anohter column....